# React router page load issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router

React router page load always keep the scrolling position same. Is there a simple way to keep the scroll position in a certain position of the page?

Answer (score 1):

```
useEffect(() => {
  let unlisten = history.listen(({ location, action }) => {
    console.log(action, location.pathname, location.state);    
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
  });
  return () => unlisten() 
}, [])
```

You can listen to history change and scroll to top, or any other position you want, at history change. You can keep this code in your first, say `App`, component.